# Hibernate Windows 10 PC after updating

Tags: windows-10

My Windows 10 PC will periodically wake up from hibernation in the middle of the night to run Windows Update. I wouldn't mind this so much if it went back into hibernate mode when it was complete. Is there a way to set Update to put my computer back into whatever power state it was in originally when updates complete, or even just to force it to hibernate after updating?

Answer (score 0):

This is something I had significant frustration with myself, and unfortunately the only solutions I found were

1. To disable sleep timers, thus preventing my laptop waking up in the night.
2. Disable "Fast start-up", so that a shutdown is actually a shutdown, and sleep timers will not work. This can be done by following these steps:

   Control Panel -> Power options -> Choose what the power buttons do - > "Change settings that are currently unavailable" (requires admin permissions, near the top of the window) - > Scroll down to see the check box "Turn on fast -startup"
3. Set the power options of the system to trigger hibernation after X minutes of inactivity.

I hope one of those is satisfactory, I can't say they really were for me, although they do prevent the problem from occurring.

Comment: how do you disable fast start up?

Comment: Control Panel -> Power options -> Choose what the power buttons do - > "Change settings that are currently unavailable" (requires admin permissions, near the top of the window) - > Scroll down to see the check box "Turn on fast -startup"

Comment: Edit your answer to include this.